# Issue with rails saying a nested model's field is blank when it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an issue with getting a nested model to save properly when it has validations. This seems to only be happening to a single field in this model.

I have two models, a Veterinarian

```
class Veterinarian < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :licenses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :licenses, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

and a License

```
class License < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :veterinarian
  validates :number, :expiration_date, presence: true
end
```

My controller action is doing nothing but calling `Veterinarian.create(vet_params)` with `vet_params` looking like this rendered out as JSON.

```
{  
  "zip_code":"",
  "title":"",
  "bio":"",
  "photo":"",
  "licenses_attributes":{  
    "0":{  
      "number":"6436436446",
      "expiration_date":"09/06/2018",
      "_destroy":"false"
    },
    "1":{  
      "number":"Test Number",
      "expiration_date":"09/16/2020",
      "_destroy":"false"
    },
    "2":{  
      "number":"test 2",
      "expiration_date":"09/30/2016",
      "_destroy":"false"
    }
  }
}
```

The proper params are being sent to 'create()' however with the nested licenses it keeps throwing an error saying expiration_date cannot be blank. This is ONLY happening for additional licenses past the first one. The first one validates just fine.

I am at a loss as to what would be causing this. I've never seen this happen before. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is Rails 5 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expiration date is invalid.

```
"1":{  
  "number":"Test Number",
  "expiration_date":"09/16/2020",
  "_destroy":"false"
},
```

In rails console try,

```
date = Date.parse("09/16/2020")
```

You will get error

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (irb):20:in `parse'
from (irb):20
```

But while saving record, rails is skipping this error and expiration_date is set to nil, and following validation is raising error which says expiration date can not be blank.

```
validates :number, :expiration_date, presence: true
```

Change expiration date to "09/09/2020" from "09/16/2020". Your code will work fine.

Comment: Nice catch! This fixed it.